# Unable to execute GCP gsutil command in Windows11 CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to execute **gsutil commands** in Windows11 CLI.

I am providing you the command and relevant error:

1. `gsutil ls`

```
ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project. Permission 'storage.buckets.list' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
```

2. `gsutil mb [BUCKET NAME]`

```
Creating [BUCKET NAME]...
You are attempting to access protected data with no configured
credentials. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/console#/project
and sign up for an account, and then run the "gcloud auth login"
command to configure gsutil to use these credentials.
```

*Note: I have tired this after executing `gcloud auth login` and the login was successful.*

**My IAM admin roles has the following storage permissions:**
[image: Admin Owner permission]

I am not sure what have been done with this and the entire things works fine in the google console. Can anyone helps me in solving this issue.

***Thank you in advance to those who lend a hand with this.***

Things I tried:

- Installed Google SDK
- Run `gcloud init`
- Run `gcloud auth login` -> Successful
- Run `gsutil command` -> Failed

Comment: 1) What is `my local console`? Specify operating system, version, etc. instead 2) `Anonymous caller` means that you have not configured the CLI tools with credentials. 3) Your list of roles does not include Google Cloud Storage. 4) What is `root account`? Please specify what you are using.

Comment: Hi John, Updated the question.

Comment: I am trying to execute gsutil command from Windows11 powershell. Installed and authourized my account using `gcloud auth login`. But still getting error.

Comment: If this problem is related to IAM roles, please guide me.

Comment: Start with this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) on Cloud Storage permissions. The simple solution is to add the IAM role `roles/viewer`.

Comment: I have the Admin role, still not able list gcs files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple, I tried to look into my `gcloud` configuration.

```
gcloud config list
```

Output

```
[accessibility]
screen_reader = True
[compute]
region = us-central1
zone = us-central1-c
[core]
account = [ACCOUNT]
disable_usage_reporting = False
pass_credentials_to_gsutil = False
project = [PROJECT_ID]
```

The `pass_credentials_to_gsutil` was set to `False` and I changed it into `True` using the following command.

```
gcloud config set pass_credentials_to_gsutil True
```

Voila, now able to list and create buckets from my Windows11 CLI.

Comment: If `pass_credentials_to_gsutil=False`, you can configure `gsutil` to use credentials independent of `gcloud`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250305/8016720)

Comment: Sure @JohnHanley will look into it.